# Is it possible to reset the displayed URL after a function call in Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have a function in a controller (`public function Sort($field, $dir)`) which sorts incoming data based on the provided field in the specified direction. This function is accessed by the user interacting with the displayed view by clicking on a green (or red) arrow...

Unfortunately, after this function is called, the URL retains the format to make the function call which is... kind of annoying.

It goes from `http://foo.bar` to `http://foo.bar/sort/FIELD/asc`.

After the function call to sort the table, I would like to return to `foo.bar` rather than have the `foo.bar/sort/FIELD/asc` present within the web browser...

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: one advantage for the long url -- the user can make a bookmark which will work.

Answer (score 0):

Several different ways to do this! (The beautify of programming, amirite?)

---

### Option 1: Redirects with Flashdata

You could redirect to process the data using the original url (http://foo.bar/sort/FIELD/asc) then do a redirect, set_flashdata, and then have the original http://foo.bar look for flashdata before loading.

```
function sort($field, $sort) {
    //do stuff
    $this->session->set_flashdata('sort_result', $sort_result);
}

function index() {
    if ($this->session->flashdata('sort_result')) {
        //do fanciness
    } else {
        //do normal things.
    }
}
```

**Drawbacks:**
Extra step from having to direct/redirect which could annoy users and frankly looks kinda bad, also flashdata would probably require a JSON result be passed instead of a full PHP Object.

---

### Option 2: Ye Ole Javascript (AJAX):

Load data into your table using javascript, which would keep the user on the same page, logic gets to be a little weird though.

**PHP Side:**

```
function sort($field, $sort) {
    echo $this->load->view('sorted_table_view', $sort_result, TRUE);
}

function index() {
   //Normal
}
```

**Javascript Side:**

```
(function() {
   $.get('<?= site_url('sort/field/asc'); ?>', function(data) {
      //Data is the echoed view.
      $('#mydiv').html(data);
   });
});
```

---

Anyways, these are just two quick ways you could do it. There are many more I'm sure!